# Twitter v2 引用リツイートを検索

Tags: google-apps-script, twitter

目的：
Twitter V2で1週間以内の指定した日時以降に自分のツイートについた引用リツイート全てと、引用元のツイートのIDを取得したい。
引用元がどのツイートかは指定しない。

Google Apps Scriptを使っています。
Twitter v2のsearch APIを使っています。
エンドポイントのURLは以下のように設定しました。

```
const username = "xxxxx";
const endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query="+ encodeURIComponent('url:"https://twitter.com/"' + username + "/ is:quote");
```

出力

```
{ data: 
   [ 
     (省略)
     { edit_history_tweet_ids: [Object],
       id: '(引用リツイートのツイートID)',
       text: '(引用リツイートの本文)' } ],
  meta: 
   { newest_id: 'xxxxx',
     oldest_id: 'xxxxx',
     result_count: 10,
     next_token: 'xxxxx' } }
```

次のことがしたいです。
・引用リツイートそのものだけでなく、元のツイートのIDを取得したい
・10件のみでなく全てを取得したい
・指定した日時以降の引用リツイートを取得したい

どのようにパラメーターをセットしたらいいでしょうか。
調べても分からないため、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

あるツイートで引用されているツイートの ID を取得するには、クエリパラメータ―に expansion を指定すれば良いです: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/expansions

具体的には `expansions=referenced_tweets.id` を指定すれば良いです。以下リクエストとレスポンスの例です。

```bash
% curl -s 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Fnekketsuuu%2F%22+is%3Aquote+-is%3Aretweet&expansions=referenced_tweets.id' -H 'Authorization: Bearer 省略' | jq
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1619368289658093570",
      "text": "テスト2 https://t.co/eO9lOSxD53",
      "referenced_tweets": [
        {
          "type": "quoted",
          "id": "1619368244422533122"
        }
      ],
      "edit_history_tweet_ids": [
        "1619368289658093570"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "includes": {
    "tweets": [
      {
        "id": "1619368244422533122",
        "text": "テスト",
        "edit_history_tweet_ids": [
          "1619368244422533122"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "meta": {
    "newest_id": "1619368289658093570",
    "oldest_id": "1619368289658093570",
    "result_count": 1
  }
}
```

全件取得するにはクライアント側でページネーション処理を行ってください: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/pagination

ある日付より前のツイートを取得するには `until:` が使えます: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators